# Memory usage by Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm running a Matlab code in the HPC of my university. I have two versions of the code. The second version, despite generating a smaller array, seems to require more memory. I would like your help to understand if this is in fact the case and why.

Let me start from some preliminary lines:

```
clear
rng default
%Some useful components
n=7^4;
vectors{1}=[1,20,20,20,-1,Inf,-Inf];
vectors{2}=[-19,19,19,19,-20,Inf,-Inf];
vectors{3}=[-19,0,0,0,-20,Inf,-Inf];
vectors{4}=[-19,0,0,0,-20,Inf,-Inf];
T_temp = cell(1,4);
[T_temp{:}] = ndgrid(vectors{:}); 
T_temp = cat(4+1, T_temp{:});
T = reshape(T_temp,[],4); %all the possible 4-tuples from vectors{1}, ..., vectors{4}
```

This is the first version 1 of the code: I construct the matrix `D1` listing **all possible pairs of unordered rows** from `T`

```
indices_pairs=pairIndices(n);
D1=[T(indices_pairs(:,1),:) T(indices_pairs(:,2),:)];
```

This is the second version of the code: I construct the matrix `D2` listing **a random draw** of `m=10^6` unordered pairs of rows from `T`

```
m=10^6;
p=n*(n-1)/2;
random_indices_pairs = randperm(p, m).';
[C1, C2] = myind2ind (random_indices_pairs, n);
indices_pairs=[C1 C2];
D2=[T(indices_pairs(:,1),:) T(indices_pairs(:,2),:)];
```

---

My question: when generating `D2` the HPC goes out of memory. When generating `D1` the HPC works fine, despite `D1` being a larger array than `D2`. Why is that the case?

---

These are complementary functions used above:

```
function indices = pairIndices(n)
  [y, x] = find(tril(logical(ones(n)), -1)); %#ok<LOGL>
  indices = [x, y];
end


function [R , C] = myind2ind(ii, N)
    jj = N * (N - 1) / 2 + 1  - ii;
    r = (1 + sqrt(8 * jj)) / 2;
    R = N  -floor(r);
    idx_first = (floor(r + 1) .* floor(r)) / 2;
    C = idx_first-jj + R + 1;
end
```

Comment: What is `myind2ind`?

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I forgot to add it.

Comment: use `profile -memory on` to see for yourself. In the second instance, you are allocating many additional arrays. You can scale it down to small arrays, the relative scaling should remain the same.

Comment: Running the second version in octave only uses 199 Mb of memory that is relatively small. Have you checked the available memory?

Comment: I don't know what happens: i have requested 7 Giga and the second version still gives out of memory message.

Comment: "When generating D1 the HPC works fine, despite D1 being a smaller array than D2." <- do you mean "D1 being a larger array than D1"?